# Sequential definition of limits of functions.

Tags: limits, functions, proof-writing

I have the following question.

[image]

I wrote for $a)$ that it is true since you can assume what is given, and so you know that any sequence with $x_n \ne a$ and $x_n \to a$ has $\lim_{n \to \inf} F(x_n) = L$. But if $\lim_{n \to \inf} F(x_n)=L$, then $\lim_{n \to \inf} F(x_{2n}) = L$ since both $n \to \inf \iff 2n \to \inf$ and the sequence $\{x_{2n}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$. Is this valid?

For $b)$, I tried a variety of sequences and functions as a counterexample but was not able to find a counterexample that worked. For example, I thought $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\{x_n\}=\frac{1}{n}$ was promising, but it didn't work since $F(x)$ was not defined at $a$.

For $c)$, since it builds on the previous questions, I do not know where to proceed.

I would appreciate hints and next steps on where to go from here.

Note that I do not specifically want a full-fledged, proof, just an explanation, with a counterexample if the statement is false, as the question states.

Comment: "inf"->"\infty".  Please type the question (with MathJax markup) as well so that it can be found by searches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Hints only:

For b):  Could we choose all the $x_{2n}$ on one side of $a$ and the $x_{2n+1}$ on the other side of $a$?  Does $F$ have to be continuous, or can it have a step discontinuity somewhere?

For c):  This doesn't really build on the prior problems.  If you "shift all the sequence elements" to have index one greater and then insert a new first member (which can be anything in the domain of $F$ since convergence does not care about the details of $x_1$), the even index members become odd index members and vice versa.  From
$$ x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots  $$
to
$$ y_1 = \mathrm{anything}, y_2 = x_1, y_3 = x_2, \dots  $$
So now you know what the even and odd index subsequences converge to...

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: I would like more detail for the answer to c). I understand what you are saying but do not grasp how to use it.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence converging to, but avoiding, $a$.  If the even index subsequence converges to $a$, there is an  $N_{\mathrm{even}}$ such that $x_{2n}$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $a$ for $2n > N_{\mathrm{even}}$.  Similarly, there is an $N_{\mathrm{odd}}$ such that $x_{2n+1}$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $a$ for $2n+1 > N_{\mathrm{odd}}$.  What can you say about every $x_i$ for $i > \max\{N_{\mathrm{even}}, N_{\mathrm{odd}}\}$?